# Visual Studio 2012 C Access Code Error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, scanf

I am working on a small homework program with C, and I encountered a very unusual issue. I was coding this in C using Visual Studio 2012. The program compiles without errors, and it also runs in cmd until a certain stage where it crashes with an exception. Please ignore the logic of the program, I cut some parts to focus on the error itself. I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank You!

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( void )
{
    int menuinput;
    int austinHour, austinMinute;
    int irishHour, irishMinute;
        printf("Insert a Number from 1-11 to select menu option: ");
        scanf_s("%d",&menuinput);
        switch(menuinput)
        {
            case 1:
            { 
                irishHour=0;
                irishMinute=0;
                austinHour=0;
                austinMinute =0; 
                printf("Enter Austin time: ");
                scanf_s("%d %d",austinHour,austinMinute);
                irishHour = (austinHour + 61);
                printf("%d %d",irishHour, austinMinute);
            }
                }
```

The error is the following when I try to run the program:

```
First-chance exception at 0x62ACD745 (msvcr110d.dll) in Lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an typo, You did not pass the address of arguments in `scanf`:

```
 printf("Enter Austin time: ");
 scanf_s("%d %d",&austinHour,&austinMinute);
                 ^^          ^^
```

And I say it is an typo because you did so correctly the fist time you use scanf:

```
scanf_s("%d",&menuinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alok Save's answer, I'm wondering if you're encountering mysterious behavioural faults from your usage of scanf. I have prepared some questions to consider. You can find the answers in [this scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html), if you need a manual.

1. `int x = scanf("%d %d", &foo, &bar);` What will x be if I enter "123 hello"?
2. Which word would you use to describe the value of bar?
3. Which character would you expect to be returned by getchar()?
4. `do { x = scanf("%d", &bar); printf("x: %d\n", x); } while (x == 0);` What would you expect from this code, considering "hello" still remains on the stream from the last conversion failure?
5. `int y = scanf("%d", &foo);` Would you expect y to be positive if scanf encountered an EOF before it could put anything into foo? EOF can be sent to stdin by pressing CTRL+Z in Windows, or CTRL+D in Linux.
6. `int z = scanf("%d %d", &foo, &bar);` What would you expect z to be, assuming scanf successfully assigned values to the two variables foo and bar?